# how to download a filefield file in django view

Tags: django, download, filefield

I have filefield in my django model:

```
file=models.FileField(verbose_name=u'附件',upload_to='attachment/%Y/%m/%d',max_length=480)
```

This file will display in the web page with link "http://test.com.cn/home/projects/89/attachment/2012/02/24/sscsx.txt"

What I want to do is when user click the file link, it will download the file automatically;
Can anyone tell me how to do this in the view?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can try the following code, assuming that `object_name` is an object of that model:

```
filename = object_name.file.name.split('/')[-1]
response = HttpResponse(object_name.file, content_type='text/plain')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename

return response
```

See the following part of the Django documentation on sending files directly: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment

Comment: how did you get object_name to that view? what URL params did you use?

Comment: The object_name doesn't matter as it simply represents a Django Model object. You can retrieve the object any way you like.

Comment: You could also use os.path.basename to filter filename instead of using .split('/').

eg. `filename = os.path.basename(object_name.file.name)`.

This will work regardless of OS.

Comment: what if the filename is UTF-8 string?

Answer (score 6):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage

> All that will be stored in your database is a path to the file (relative to MEDIA_ROOT). You'll most likely want to use the convenience url function provided by Django. For example, if your ImageField is called mug_shot, you can get the absolute path to your image in a template with {{ object.mug_shot.url }}.