# How to open a Document whilst in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have an object that contains a database record that has a ***FileField*** which points to a `.pdf`, `.txt` or `.doc` or `.docx`.

In my django template i want to create a link which when clicked opens the file, in the machines default tool for opening that file, How do i do this?

**I currently have:**

```
<a href="#">{{ object.file.name }}</a>
```

I would like to click this link and have the document opened.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462999/how-to-download-a-filefield-file-in-django-view

Comment: `{{ object.file.url }}` will give you the URL to the file.