# Downloading a FileField with a View

Tags: python, django

I have a table which presents order information - attached to each order is a file.  This file's file path displays as a link in the table already, but I am unable to download by clicking it.  I would like to be able to click this link and have the proper .docx download.

I am referencing: [how to download a filefield file in django view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462999/how-to-download-a-filefield-file-in-django-view)

but I really don't understand how this solution is working.  Is no URL needed? How does the view know which file to pick? I opened a previous question and got marked as a duplicate and pointed to this link, but I really don't understand the solution that was given here. Do I need to somehow pass the pk of the order or something?  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is my code.

models.py

```
class Orders(models.Model):

...

order_file = models.FileField(upload_to='web_unit', null=True, blank=True)

...
    def __str__(self):

       return self.reference
```

index.html

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="main_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" style="width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      ....
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    {% for order in orders %}

    <tr>

      <td>
        <!-- Update book buttons -->
      <button type="button" class="update-book btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="color: #FFCF8B; border-color: #FFCF8B; background-color: #FFF;" data-id="{% url 'order_update' order.pk %}">
        <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
      </button>
      </td>

   ....

      <td><a href="{{ order.order_file.url }}">Download</a></td> #this is the link

    </tr>
    {% endfor %}


  </tbody>
</table>
```

When the link in the table is clicked - I'd like for the file to be downloaded - I need help on how to define the URL and the View to make this happen.

Right now when I click the link I get an error showing all the urls that were tried.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit complex stuff at first, but let me break it down for you.

First of all, the files you upload thorough *Django* are stored somewhere in the *Filesystem* (in case of default settings). This usually means your uploaded files go to your `/media` folder which is in the same directory as your other Django files are. 
The path to the *media* folder can be defined in your Django settings file using the `MEDIA_ROOT` parameter. By default its probably next to your `manage.py` file.

To be able to download your uploaded files, you need to serve the files using a webserver (Apache, nginx, etc...). Here's a config snippet from a classic **nginx** setup:

```
# Media files
    location /media {
        alias /home/riverman/my-django-project/media;
    }
```

This means, your uploaded file could be accessed (and downloaded) thorough a browser using the following *imaginary* link:
`http://my-django-project.test/media/images/cat.png`

Now here's the tricky part: Django does not store the full url (`http://my-django-project.test/media/images/cat.png`) to your file in the database, but instead, only the static part of it (`/images/cat.png`). Both the media folder's name (`media` in this example) and the website's URL (`my-django-project.test`) are subject to later change so it would not be clever to store it all in the database, but instead, you generate the full URL on-the-fly.

When you access the path to your desired file (`{{ order.order_file.url }}`) you only receive a partial information, something like this: `/media/images/cat.png`.

You need to combine this partial information with your site's url. Here's an example how i'd do it. Add this in your `views.py`:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
current_site.domain
```

and update your `index.html` to this:

`<td><a href="{{ current_site.domain }}/{{ order.order_file.url }}">Download</a></td>`

To setup a local webserver on your development machine is out of scope for this question, but you can refer to this question: [Best lightweight web server (only static content) for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050851/best-lightweight-web-server-only-static-content-for-windows)

Good luck!